# How Can I send multiple API request from one function altogether

Tags: javascript, api, cypress, performance-testing, web-api-testing

I want to send Multiple API request to a API end point all together. just to test performance of the Api.
what are the various ways to do it. I have a list of API endpoints of API which I want to send request. and want to know best, average and worst response time.

using Axios request in JavaScript I am trying to send request but only able to do it one by one and in this approach not getting result I want as the request are asynchronous in nature.

What I want to Do:-

Api End Point list-> request to all end point in one go -> best, Worst, average response time.

any approach to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can but you cannot test API backend performance with this because you cannot send more than 6 [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests at a time (unless you [configure your browser to be able to execute more](https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/985646))

So I would recommend considering using a [dedicated load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) for performance testing of your API backend

Answer (score 0):

Since you're familiar to javascript, I recommend checking out K6: https://k6.io/
It's a dedicated performance test tool using JS libraries and fast to setup

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).